# Sorting until we have the lowest half of the sorted array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am currently trying to get the values that are in the lowest half of an array of data. This array in unsorted at first.

From this:

```
{4,6,9,3,8,5}
```

To this :

```
{3,4,5,6,9,8} or {3,4,5}
```

An easy solution would be to sort the array (using quicksort) and then use only the values stored in the first half of the sorted array.
However, since quicksort and most efficient sorting algorithms will sort the entire array while I only need the first 50%, this seems like a waste of ressources. Note that performance is an issue in this project.

Knowing that a full sort is O(n log n) and that a sort that stops after it finds the lowest element is O(n), I can easily build a simple algorithm that will have a complexity of n/2 * n to find the lowest 50%. But is that really better than a full quicksort?

To be clear, what would be the best sort to use if we want only the lowest half of the values in an array?
If the 50% was smaller (like 1%), a sequential search of the lowest elements would of course be the fastest solution, but at what % does it become slower than a quicksort?

I am coding in C++ and using vectors, but this question should be pretty general.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
std::partial_sort(start, middle, end);
```

Comment: I was under the impression that partial_sort was only sorting some part of the array, but it seems to be what I need after reading the doc carefully.
"Performs approximately (end-start)*log(middle-start) comparisons.", which is somewhat better than quicksort...
Any idea what algorithm it uses?

Comment: @AlexMillette: It looks like GCC uses a variation on heap sort. It could also be done with a small modification to quick sort - the first stage would choose the end of the range you want as the pivot, then only sort the lower sub-range.

Comment: Probably some form of quicksort which discards any partitions that start after n/2

Comment: I may do some more searches on this subject, but as of now this seems like a great solution for my problem. Thank you Mike.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It doesn't use [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)? (which of course, includes heapsort in one stage)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: No, it does a heap-based partition, followed by heap-sort on the lower partition (in 4.6 at least, I haven't looked at other versions).

Comment: @rhalbersma: No, you are incorrect. There would be no need for `std::partial_sort` (I presume that's what you mean) if it worked the way you describe, since it would be equivalent to `std::sort(start, middle);`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the lower half sorted, use `std::nth_element`.  If you need the lower half sorted and the vector contains fewer than 100,000 elements, use `std::partial_sort`, if your vector is larger then use `std::nth_element` to partition the vector into lower half and upper half, then use `std::qsort` on the lower half.  I've confirmed this on an Intel Xeon X5570 @ 2.93GHz running CentOS with g++ 4.4.3 and give timings at the end of this answer.  Scott Meyers and others have found it astonishing that `std::nth_element` followed by `std::qsort` can be that much faster than `std::partial_sort` for large vectors:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t745258-nth_element-sort-versus-partial_sort.html

If you just want the lowest half of the values and don't need those to be sorted then `std::nth_element` is fastest (complexity is linear).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/

```
// nth_element example (modified to partition into lower/upper halves)
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    vector<int> myvector;
    vector<int>::iterator it;

    // set some values:
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);   // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

    random_shuffle (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());

    // using default comparison (operator <):
    nth_element (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+myvector.size()/2, myvector.end());

    // print out content:
    cout << "myvector contains:";
    for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
        cout << " " << *it;

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On an Intel Xeon X5570 @ 2.93GHz running CentOS and using g++ 4.4.3 I measure the following times.  It is clear from the data that `std::nth_element` is linear and faster than `std::partial_sort` for all sizes, and 94 times faster when N is 1 billion elements.

```
N =       1000 nth_element   0.0000082 sec
N =       1000 nth + qsort   0.0001114 sec
N =       1000 partial_sort  0.0000438 sec

N =      10000 nth_element   0.0000592 sec
N =      10000 nth + qsort   0.0005639 sec
N =      10000 partial_sort  0.0005271 sec

N =     100000 nth_element   0.00095 sec
N =     100000 nth + qsort   0.00683 sec
N =     100000 partial_sort  0.00697 sec

N =    1000000 nth_element   0.0086 sec
N =    1000000 nth + qsort   0.0831 sec
N =    1000000 partial_sort  0.1227 sec

N =   10000000 nth_element   0.0700 sec
N =   10000000 nth + qsort   0.9307 sec
N =   10000000 partial_sort  2.7006 sec

N =  100000000 nth_element   0.8147 sec
N =  100000000 nth + qsort  10.7602 sec
N =  100000000 partial_sort 56.7105 sec

N = 1000000000 nth_element   10.055 sec
N = 1000000000 nth + qsort  123.703 sec
N = 1000000000 partial_sort 947.949 sec
```

Comment: While the complexity is indeed linear, the constant factor is fairly large that the benefits start to show only when there are a large number of elements.

Comment: That's not my experience, what compiler/library/machine are you using to make that observation?

Comment: Interesting. I'm assuming that you made your tests with the 50% limit. I wonder what would be the results if we were to change this limit. That is, when approaching 100%, would partial_sort gain the upper hand? And what about quicksort? This is more about curiosity than my project though, so I won't do too much tests on it. Still, this answer is quite good.

Comment: Alex, yes the tests were with 50% limit.  I might run a test at 95% and report the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do a partial quicksort, stop the algorithm after it has sorted at least half your array. See [here](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/quick-sort) for a visual representation.

In the worst case, the entire array will be sorted, and the best case half will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there could be any algorithm with less than O(log N) time complexity for this problem. But in average cases, this could be enhanced.

You can fine tune the quick sort algorithm for this particular use case as below.

You may already know, quick sort comprises of an internal algorithm called partition, which partitions the array into two which has a pivot element in the middle such that values on the left are less than the pivot and values on the right are greater the the pivot.

So, your problem reduces to a problem of partition an array so that you have equal number of elements on either side of the pivot.

The following algorithm should work, which splits the array into two, so that lower half of the array has element less than median and the upper has element greater than the median.

```
void split_the_array(int[] array, int a, int b, int m)
{
    p = partition(array, a, b)
    if (p == m) return;
    if (p < m) split_the_array(p+1, b, m)
    else       split_the_array(a, p-1, m)
}
```

Invoke this function as

```
split_the_array(arr, 0, len(arr), len(arr) / 2)
```

After the execution of the function, all the elements to the left of (len(arr) / 2) should be less than it and those on the right should be greater than it.

You should easily get the algorithm for partition.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort everything with [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) sort, it might be faster than quicksort. I'm not sure if it's faster than partial sort. It is useful if you need to sort a limited range of numbers (32bits representation for example)
[Here](http://infoarena.ro/job_detail/371374?action=view-source) is an implementation I made some time ago
**edit:** seems that [this](http://infoarena.ro/job_detail/775877?action=view-source) implementation of radix sort is even faster